# Insert SDO_GEOMETRY in cx_oracle with SDO POINT

Tags: python, sdo-geometry, cx-oracle

I am trying to create a SDO_Geometry in Python so I can insert it into Oracle. I want it to be lat long so I just need a sdo_point_type

I have gotten as far as this

```
typeObj = prdconn.gettype("SDO_GEOMETRY")
elementInfoTypeObj = prdconn.gettype("SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY")
#pointTypeObj = prdconn.gettype("SDO_POINT_TYPE")
pointTypeObj = prdconn.gettype("SDO_POINT_TYPE")
obj= typeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_GTYPE = 2001
obj.SDO_SRID = 4326
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO = elementInfoTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO.extend([1, 1003, 3])
```

I know I don't need a SDO_ELEM_INFO, I just can't create the SDO_POINT. When I try like below it always errors out with cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value cannot be converted to a database value.
Creating a SDO_ELEM_INFO seems to be o.k

```
obj.SDO_POINT= pointTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_POINT.extend([-71.48923,42.72347,None])
```

The bottom of the create table statement is as follows

```
"CENTER" "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY" 
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXXXXXX" 
 VARRAY "CENTER"."SDO_ELEM_INFO" STORE AS SECUREFILE LOB 
  ( TABLESPACE "XXXXXXX" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  CACHE  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 VARRAY "CENTER"."SDO_ORDINATES" STORE AS SECUREFILE LOB 
  ( TABLESPACE "XXXXXX" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  CACHE  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
```

Comment: close try https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181966/276

Comment: I did find that incident and it has no example for a sdo_point and I can't find it and I tried what I said above and it won't create the sdo_point

Comment: It depends on how the TABLE was created SDO_POINT_TYPE or SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY https://www.spdba.com.au/convert-single-point-stored-in-sdo_ordinates-to-sdo_point_type/

Comment: I have added the bottom of my create table statement.  Did I do something wrong there?  I thought i would want the lat long in the sdo_point part of the sdo_geomentry